# IE8 CSS Negative Margin Pulling Up Parent Element

Tags: css

I am using a negative margin to pull up an `<li>` for a overlay effect. This effect works in all browsers, including IE7, but does not in IE8. IE8 seems to pull the entire `<ul>` up -4px (the negative margin height)

I am done trying to fight it and would appreciate any recommendations by this community on how to resolve this. I'd prefer to stick as closely as possible with my current styles as `position:absolute` can cause `z-index` problems in IE7. Here's the page - http://actorstheatre.org/. It's the main navigation at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `position:relative;top:-4px;` instead?

Comment: It actually is `position: relative;`. Adding `top` in place of `margin` causes all browsers to behave funky, albeit consistent.

Comment: Funky in what way? Can you make a simplified version of this?

Comment: Funky as in that didn't fix anything, but made it worse. I understand what you are getting at. The goal was not to rework all the styles for this nav. But yet to understand what is going on with IE8. That's the *challenge* ;)

Comment: i dont see it on the li or a. or is it conditionally specified for those?

Answer (score 0):

If it's only in IE8 you can force it into IE7 compatiblity mode.

```
<meta content='IE=7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533876.aspx

Comment: I realize this, but that is not a solution in my mind. Thanks though.